# Why is the price increase always zero?

Tags: c, function, user-input

I need some help with a program I've been making for the university. Inside this program, it must be a function that must increase the price of a type of product according to a value given by the user. Fine, I've written the following function:

```
void increase_price(struct reg products[SIZE], int count){
    int i;
    float increase, perc;
    char option;
    printf("Type of product: ");
    fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &option);
    printf("\nThe increase percentage: ");
    fflush(stdin); scanf("%f", &perc); 
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        if(products[i].type == option){
            increase = products[i].price * (perc/100);
            products[i].price += increase;
        }
    }
}// Fim increase_price()
```

The problem is that the increase's calculation always results in zero. I can't understand why it's happening. I also tried to print the 'perc' variable after receiving its input, but strangely it didn't work.

Some more code:

- The definition of struct reg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define SIZE 100

struct reg{
    int cod;
    char desc[30], type;
    float price;
};
```

- At the main function, the only usefull thing for this function is the call of the function itself, and, sure, the declaration of the struct and the count variable(whose value comes from another function according to the number of products).
- The type is defined in another function in which you can add products. it's a litteral value like P (for pants), T (for T-shirt) etc.

Comment: Undefined behavior: `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: Is `products[i].type == option` ever `true`?

Comment: "I also tried to print the 'perc' variable after receiving its input..." that means, your question is not about calculating some value but about doing input correctly. You should always check return value of `scanf` and similar functions. Does reading `option` work correctly?

Comment: Just some wild guess as you do not provide enough code... You might read some numbers or strings via `scanf` before you call that function. These calls would leave the trailing `\n` in input buffer and reading `option` would read that character. As a result the character entered for `option` would end up in `perc` which does not evaluate to some number...

Comment: Instead of `fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &option);` add a space before `%c` to filter the whitespace like `scanf(" %c", &option);`. This is how `scanf` is intended to be used. You don't need it before `%f`. All format specifiers except `%c` and `%n` and `%[]` automatically filter whitespace.

Comment: I would say your code snippet isn't complete : what's the definition of `struct reg` ? Where do you output anything ? What is your input ? There is currently a lot of possible different reasons on why you observe this result. Have a look on [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ...and if you feel a need to clear the 'type-ahead' then `scanf` is the wrong function to use: use `fgets` instead, to read whole lines, and apply `sscanf` or other.

Comment: *fflush(stdin)* should be *fflush(stdout)*

Comment: What type is `products[i].price`?

Comment: Neil, products[i].price is a float.

Comment: I just add some more information.